# Whats the equivalent to String... in scala

Tags: java, scala

The title asks the question.  Basically I am using a java library that takes a String... as a parameter.  How can I call that in my scala code?

I'll add a bit more:

from scala code

```
def myScalaFunc(params:String*) {
   val myJavaClass = new JavaClass()
   myJavaClass(params)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to expand the `params` into a series of arguments, not just a single collection argument.  The easiest way to do this is by saying `params: _*`.

If the Java looks like:

```
public class VarargTest {
  public void javaFunc(String... args) { 
    // something
  }
}
```

Then the Scala caller looks like:

```
def scalaFunc(params: String*) = 
  (new VarargTest).javaFunc(params: _*)
```

Comment: @chiappone This answer provides the solution to your problem, but you should understand _why_ your code wasn't working—because, intuitively, one would think that it _would_ work! See, when you're calling `scalaFunc`, sure, the parameters you're passing into it are interpreted as a varargs of Strings, but once you're _inside of_ `scalaFunc`, `params` is actually considered to be a `Seq[String]`. _However_, if you ever need to turn any kind of `Seq` into a varargs, `: _*` is the ever-so-sweet syntactic sugar for doing so, and that's exactly what dhg is employing here in the call to `javaFunc`.

Answer (score 5):

If the method is defined:

```
void method(String... param)
```

Then either call it like this:

```
method("String 1", "String 2")
```

Or expand a Seq using this special syntax:

```
method(Seq("String 1", "String 2"): _*)
```

Given your example code (I'm assuming my edit is correct):

```
myJavaClass.myJavaMethod(params: _*)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, this is the syntax for a method that receives a variable number of arguments:

```
void method(String... param)
```

In Scala, the equivalent syntax is this:

```
def method (param:String*)
```

Comment: yeah but the signature doesn't seem to match up when I try to do myJavaMethod(param) where param is a String*

Comment: @chiappone See my comment above, if param is defined as String* then use the Seq expansion syntax to call myJavaMethod with it.